# Any rule based classifier implementations in R that can handle numeric attributes?

Tags: machine-learning, r

I'm looking for any rule based classifier implementation with the exception of C4.5rules that can handle numeric attributes in R.

I've taken a look at RWeka however numeric attributes are not supported. Any alternatives?

Comment: I can't find any PRISM or DDPMine implementations, only RIPPER.